# InvalidValueError: setIcon: in property rotation: not a number

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, maps, google-maps-markers

I just want to ask I am using google map and MarkerWithLabel for V3 1.1.10,before it works fine,but now it suddenly have this errors

> InvalidValueError: setIcon: in property rotation: not a number

**Updated** 
I found out that this is the causes of error **rotation: heading[i]**
this works fine before when I am using googple api v3.17

```
 marker = new MarkerWithLabel({


                            map: map,
                            labelClass: "themarkersclass",
                            labelStyle: {opacity: 1.0},
                            labelContent: 'labelcontent here',
                            icon: {
                                path: carauto,
                                scale: .6,
                                strokeColor: 'white',
                                strokeWeight: .7,
                                fillOpacity: 0.8,
                                fillColor: 'red',
                                offset: '5%',
                                rotation: heading[i],
                                anchor: new google.maps.Point(10, 50)
                            },
                            id: com_name[i]


                        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well the error its pretty obvious seems like you are not passing numbers into the setIcon.

it should be some reasons about this.
you are using some `var of = value`; and setting it like `setIcon:of`,
where fo is  `[object,object]`.

you have some `<blankspace> // not sure about this`.

Maybe more code about this will be great

Change `rotation:parseInt(header[i])` just to be sure that we are passing an integer value into the `rotation` field

Comment: Before this works fine i did not change with my code,but now suddenly i get this error.I don't know maybe google updating again there api

Comment: did you make sure that the value you are passing into setIcon its actually an accepted value, `this.setIcon(variableTest); console.log(variableTest)` for example, im working right now with gmaps and there is not change, maybe you did change something, be sure that `variableTest` don't return undefined

Comment: this the one that causes the error rotation: heading[i],it is in markerwithlabel,that works before,

Comment: if i remove that the error are gone,but I don't have the heading anymore

Comment: and `console.log(heading[i])` what returns?

Comment: `console.log(isNaN(heading[i]))` what returns?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71138/discussion-between-jemz-and-ethaan).